# Make script terminate when background zenity dialog is closed

Tags: bash, zenity

I have written a fairly simple script here that is meant to display a text info dialog using `zenity` and continuously read data from a remote TCP connection and display it in the dialog. This works... However I would like for the entire script to terminate if I close the `zenity` dialog.

Is there a way to do this? I don't think I can check for anything in the while loop, because the script could be stalled on reading the data from the remote TCP connection.

```
#!/bin/bash

on_exit() {
        zenity --display=:0 --error --text="Script has exited." &
}

# Options
while getopts "a:p:t:" OPTION; do case "$OPTION" in
        a) address="$OPTARG";;
        p) port="$OPTARG";;
        t) title="$OPTARG";;
esac; done

exec &> >(zenity --display=:0 --text-info --title=$title || exit)
                               # doesn't make a difference?  ↑
                               # also tried &&
trap "on_exit" EXIT

while read data < /dev/tcp/$address/$port; do
        echo $data
        # ...
        # do some other stuff with the information
        # ...
done
```

**Note:** This is going to be run on IGEL Linux. I don't have the option of installing additional packages. So, ideally the solution I'm looking for is native to Bash.

---

### Update

I only had to make this modification to continue using `exec`. Or @BachLien's answer using named pipes also works.

```
PID=$$
exec &> >(zenity --display=:0 --text-info --title=$title; kill $PID)
```

Comment: Is it possible to put Zenity execution in a wrapper that waits for its termination and kills the target script afterwards?

Comment: Calling `exit` inside `>(...)` means exiting the subshell. You need to `kill` the parrent PID to terminate the parrent shell. Please consider to use named pipe (no need to install anything extra I believe) for easier coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have `zenity` installed, so I tried this script to illustrate the idea.

The program `terminal+cat` (emmulating `zenity`) is executed by the function `_dspMsg` which runs in background (child process); `cat` continuously displays messages from a file (`$m`) which is a named pipe; the parent process is `kill`ed when `terminal+cat` exits.

In the mean while, another `cat` proccess writes messsages into pipe `$m` (emmulating TPC infomation feeds); it would be killed when when `_dspMsg` exits.

```
#!/bin/bash
                              # 1) named pipe
m=`mktemp -u /tmp/msg-XXXX=`  #    get a temporary filename (for named pipe)
mkfifo "$m"                   #    create that named pipe
trap "echo END; rm $m" EXIT   #    remove that file when exit
                              # 2) zenity
_dspMsg(){                    #    continuously display messages
  urxvt -e bash -c "cat <$m"  #    terminal+cat is used in place of zenity
  kill $1                     #    kill parent pid
}                             #    to be run in background
_dspMsg $$ &                  #    $$ = proccess id
                              # 3) TCP info feeds
cat >>"$m"                    #    feeding messages using cat
                              #    cat is used in placed of TCP data feed
```

**Note:**

1. A named pipe is used as a way of communicating between parent and child processes.
2. To test that script, you may need to change `urxvt` to `xterm`, `iTerm`, or any other terminal emmulator available in your computer.

---

So, maybe it is what you need (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "a:p:t:" OPTION; do case "$OPTION" in
  a) address="$OPTARG";;
  p) port="$OPTARG";;
  t) title="$OPTARG";;
esac; done

m=`mktemp -u /tmp/msg-XXXX=`
mkfifo "$m"
trap "zenity --display=:0 --error --text='Script has exited.' & rm $m" EXIT

_dspMsg(){
  zenity --display=:0 --text-info --title="$title" <"$m"
  kill $1
}

_dspMsg $$ &

while read data < /dev/tcp/$address/$port; do
  echo $data >>"$m"
done
```

Comment: This looks promising! `$$` is new to me. I didn't know there was such a way to get the PID current script. I will have to try it Monday though. Time is up for today.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe all of the output of the `while` loop into zenity, getting rid of the need for `exec &>`.

```
while read data < "/dev/tcp/$address/$port"; do
        echo "$data"
done | zenity --display=:0 --text-info --title="$title"
```

Comment: There is additional processing in place of the echo statement I did not mention. I should have.